# Why does bitstamp have two addresses for Ripple?

Tags: ripple, ripple-gateways, bitstamp

The bitstamp address "to trust" is `rvYAfWj5gh67oV6fW32ZzP3Aw4Eubs59B`, however when you withdraw money, it you get it from `rrpNnNLKrartuEqfJGpqyDwPj1AFPg9vn1` instead. Why?

With weexchange I got the money from the same address I trusted.

Comment: May be, I think, 'to address' will not extend its trust any further, so it would be safe and no out transactions. 'From address' not trusted by anyone, and extends its trust to payee but this one funded ad hoc for transfer.

Comment: Dammit, this is a perfect example of why Ripple should not be in this Bitcoin StackExchange.  These are completely different technologies with completely different details.

Comment: @StephenGornick python is much different from mysql, but they both are topics of SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They use [hot and cold wallets](https://ripple.com/wiki/Hot_%26_cold_wallet_setup) for security reasons. The address you trust can create an infinite number of IOUs and so its key must be carefully secured. The address they transferred to you from must be able to perform transactions easily and quickly and so cannot be fully secured.